# onblur event not firing

Tags: javascript, onblur

I am not sure why this is not firing and I didnt want to spend a whole lot of time working on it. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
    function getTimes(){
        var minuteOne = document.getElementById(minOne).value;
        var minuteTwo = document.getElementById(minTwo).value;
        var minuteThree = document.getElementById(minThree).value;
        var minuteFour = document.getElementById(minFour).value;
        var minuteFive = document.getElementById(minFive).value;
        var hourOne = document.getElementById(hourOne).value;
        var hourTwo = document.getElementById(hourTwo).value;
        var hourThree = document.getElementById(hourThree).value;
        var hourFour = document.getElementById(hourFour).value;
        var hourFive = document.getElementById(hourFive).value;
        var totalMinutes = minuteOne + minuteTwo + minuteThree + minuteFour + minuteFive;
        var extraHours = totalMinutes / 60;
        var minutesLeft = totalMinutes % 60;
        var totalHours = hourOne + hourTwo + hourThree + hourFour + hourFive + extraHours;

        document.getElementById(totalMinute).value = minuteLeft;
        document.getElementById(totalHour).value = totalHours;
    }
</SCRIPT>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Time Calculator</title>

</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr align="center">
            <td>Day</td><td>Hour</td><td>Minutes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Monday</td><td><input name="hourOne" id="hourOne" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" onblur="getTimes()" /></td><td><input name="minOne" id="minOne" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" onblur="getTimes()" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tuesday</td><td><input name="hourTwo" id="hourTwo" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" onblur="getTimes()" /></td><td><input name="minTwo" id="minTwo" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" onblur="getTimes()"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Wednesday</td><td><input name="hourThree" id="hourThree" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" onblur="getTimes()" /></td><td><input name="minThree" id="minThree" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" onblur="getTimes()" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thursday</td><td><input name="hourFour" id="hourFour" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" onblur="getTimes()" /></td><td><input name="minFour" id="minFour" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" onblur="getTimes()" /></td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Friday</td><td><input name="hourFive" id="hourFive" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" onblur="getTimes()" /></td><td><input name="minFive" id="minFive" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" onblur="getTimes()" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Time</td><td><input name="totalHour" id="totalHour" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" /></td><td><input name="totalMinute" type="text" id="totalMinute" size="5" maxlength="5" value="0" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input name="getTime" type="button" value="Get Time" onclick="getTimes()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @jambriz Wow, what a nasty comment for a two year old question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementById` takes a string. You are giving it an undeclared value:

```
var minuteOne = document.getElementById(minOne).value;
```

should be

```
var minuteOne = document.getElementById("minOne").value;
```

Notice the quotes. Secondly, this line: `minuteOne + minuteTwo + minuteThree + minuteFour + minuteFive` is concating strings, not doing addition. You need to call `parseInt` on all of the values so they do addition, not concat the strings.

Thirdly, this line

```
document.getElementById('totalMinute').value = minuteLeft;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('totalMinute').value = minutesLeft;
```

Looks like you had a typo referencing your variable. With all of the fixes applied, the JavaScript looks like this:

```
function getTimes(){
    var minuteOne = parseInt(document.getElementById('minOne').value);
    var minuteTwo = parseInt(document.getElementById('minTwo').value);
    var minuteThree = parseInt(document.getElementById('minThree').value);
    var minuteFour = parseInt(document.getElementById('minFour').value);
    var minuteFive = parseInt(document.getElementById('minFive').value);
    var hourOne = parseInt(document.getElementById('hourOne').value);
    var hourTwo = parseInt(document.getElementById('hourTwo').value);
    var hourThree = parseInt(document.getElementById('hourThree').value);
    var hourFour = parseInt(document.getElementById('hourFour').value);
    var hourFive = parseInt(document.getElementById('hourFive').value);
    var totalMinutes = minuteOne + minuteTwo + minuteThree + minuteFour + minuteFive;
    var extraHours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
    var minutesLeft = totalMinutes % 60;
    var totalHours = hourOne + hourTwo + hourThree + hourFour + hourFive + extraHours;
    document.getElementById('totalMinute').value = minutesLeft;
    document.getElementById('totalHour').value = totalHours;
}
```

And it appears to work.

Comment: @shinjuo Edited to include additional bugs found.

Comment: I made a last minute change to add `var extraHours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60); ` so that the Hours text box does not contain the fractional part of the minutes.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById(totalMinute).value = minuteLeft;`

should be

`document.getElementById(totalMinute).value = minutesLeft;`

Always check your variable names.

Answer (score 1):

```
getElementById(minOne)
```

You're passing minOne, etc in as variables when you are actually trying to use them as literal strings.  Put them in quotation marks instead, ie..

> getElementById("minOne")